# Update from Apache Velocity 1.5 to 2.2 leads to parsing errors

Tags: xml, velocity

I updated a project from velocity 1.5 to 2.2 and I have now some failures in our integration tests.
For example the #xpointer tag that is part of XML is causing an ParseException.
After escaping it with \#xpointer the problem is solved.
But #xpointer is not a velocity command. Why is it recognized as command? Is it possible to let velocity ignore it without escaping? And why did it not make problems in version 1.5?

```
xlink:href="urn:uuid:#xpointer(//foo:Bar
```

Answer (score 0):

The 2.x parser introduced several new features, which may pose problem in some corner cases.

Since Velocity allows defining custom macros, the parser doesn't now at runtime whether `#xpointer` is a macro or not. It could decide to render it as is anyway when it leads to a parsing error, but this could lead to ignore real parsing errors which deserve a report.

If you want to question this behavior, you may want to [open an issue](https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/VELOCITY/issues/).

As a workaround, instead of escaping each individual `#`, you can also tell Velocity to ignore a specific part of your template with:

```
#[[ ... #xpointer(...) ... ]]#
```